Python - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'swig'
When trying to run the gymnasium package under Windows 11, Visual Studio Code, I get the following errors
PS C:\Users\[...]\Code\Gymnasium> & c:/Users/Thomas.koeppen/Code/Gymnasium/.venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/Thomas.koeppen/Code/Gymnasium/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\[...]\Code\Gymnasium\.venv\Lib\site-packages\gymnasium\envs\box2d\bipedal_walker.py", line 15, in <module>
import Box2D
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Box2D'
[...]
File "C:\Users\[...]\Code\Gymnasium\.venv\Lib\site-packages\gymnasium\envs\box2d\bipedal_walker.py", line 25, in <module>
raise DependencyNotInstalled(
gymnasium.error.DependencyNotInstalled: Box2D is not installed, run `pip install gymnasium[box2d]`

When trying to install any of the box2d modules, I again get an error message
PS C:\Users\[...]\Code\Gymnasium> pip install gymnasium[box2d]
[...]
Building wheel for box2d-py (pyproject.toml) ... error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'swig'
[...]
error: command 'C:\\Users\\[...]\\Code\\Gymnasium\\.venv\\Scripts\\swig.exe' failed with exit code 1

The swig package is missing, even though I have installed it with pip install swig:
PS C:\Users\[...]\Code\Gymnasium> pip3 install swig
Requirement already satisfied: swig in c:\users\[...]\code\gymnasium\.venv\lib\site-packages (4.2.1)

This error has kept me busy for quite some time, I would like to document the solution for any motivated peers encountering it in the future

Many answers I found online point towards using "pip install swig", installing an upgrade, using different python versions etc - all of which did not work for me:
Instead, I needed to get swigwin by hand from the official website: http://www.swig.org/download.html
Extract the archive and add the path of the extracted directory to your PATH environment variable.
In addition, you might also need to install the Microsoft Build Tools for C++ from the official website: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/visual-cpp-build-tools/
Make sure to select "Desktop development with C++" during installation
